# If G is a group and $x,a \in G$, prove that $C_G(x^{-1}ax)=x^{-1}C_G(a)x$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If G is a group and $x,a \in G$, prove that $C_G(x^{-1}ax)=x^{-1}C_G(a)x$ where $C_G$ is the centralizer.

I believe we have to do this by showing that $C_G(x^{-1}ax) \subset x^{-1}C_G(a)x$ and vice versa.

So, let $g \in C_G(x^{-1}ax)$,

then $$gx^{-1}axg^{-1} = x^{-1}ax$$

$$gx^{-1}ax = x^{-1}axg$$
$$x^{-1}ax = g^{-1}x^{-1}axg$$
$$a = xg^{-1}x^{-1}axgx^{-1}$$

So $$xgx^{-1} \in C_G(a)$$
And, $$x^{-1}C_G(a)x = g$$

The other inclusion is just reverse of the argument.

Comment: You are stucked because two terms on the RHS went missing from the first line to the second

Comment: Oops! Thank you made the correction.

Comment: Then $a= \mbox{ junk} a \mbox{ junk }^{-1}$ meaning that $\mbox{ junk } \in C_G(a)$.

Comment: Hey thanks! If you can put your comments as an answer, I'll accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is correct, you can prove both the inclusions by picking an arbitrary element of the LHS and showing that it's in the RHS and vice versa. It basically boils down to *undoing* the conjugation by $x$ or $x^{-1}$ .

Here's another way to structure a proof using more or less the same trick.

- I'm using $\overline{g}$ to mean $g^{-1}$ . I think it reads better if you have lots of group elements being multiplied together.
- I'm using $\cdot$ to explicitly represent the result of multiplying a set of group elements by a single group element (*elementwise product*), e.g. $ g \cdot S = \{ gs \mathop| s \in S \} $ and $ S \cdot g = \{sg \mathop| s \in S\}$ . The elementwise product is normally written with juxtaposition: $gS$ and $Sg$ . $(\cdot)$ has lower precedence than juxtaposition.

We want to show that the negation of the original statement implies a contradiction.

$$ C_G(\overline{x} a x) \neq \overline{x} \cdot C_G(a) \cdot x \tag{NG} $$

$$ x \cdot C_G(\overline{x} a x) \cdot \overline{x} \neq x \overline{x} \cdot C_G(a) \cdot x \overline{x} \tag{101} $$

$$ x \cdot C_G(\overline{x} a x) \cdot \overline{x} \neq C_G(a) \tag{102} $$

replace $C_G$ on LHS with its definition.

$$ x \cdot \{ g \mathop| g \in G \land g\overline{x}ax = \overline{x}axg \} \cdot \overline{x} \neq C_G(a) \tag{103} $$

bring $x \dots \overline{x}$ inside the set builder notation.

$$ \{xg\overline{x} \mathop| g \in G \land g\overline{x}ax = \overline{x}axg \} \neq C_G(a) \tag{104} $$

Rewrite LHS using a new variable $h = xg\overline{x}$ .

$$ \{ h \in G \mathop| \overline{x}hx\overline{x}ax = \overline{x}ax\overline{x}hx \} \neq C_G(a) \tag{105} $$

$$ \{ h \in G \mathop| \overline{x}hax = \overline{x}ahx \} \neq C_G(a) \tag{106} $$

Replace the condition inside the LHS of (106) with the equivalent condition $ha = ah$ . This is allowed because conjugation is invertible.

$$ \{ h \in G \mathop| ha = ah \} \neq C_G(a) \tag{107} $$

Contradiction, (107) is the definition of the centralizer.

$$ \bot $$